# Ansible AWX UI or tower-cli smart search to exclude a pattern match

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

Has anyone figured out how to exclude a pattern match in AWX smart inventory search? The documentation and other blogs seem to be a bit vauge about it.

I am aware AWX UI has some limitations hence the devs suggest using tower-cli for this purpose which we have been.

If I have following servers:

`loc1vm10a01
 loc2vm20a01
 loc1vm10b02
 loc3vm40c09
 loc1vm20a05`

I can use tower-cli smart inventory search filter like `--host-filter "search=loc1 and search=a0"` which will return **loc1vm10a01** and **loc1vm20a05**

However, what we'd ideally want is something like, include all the 'loc1' VMs but ignore VMs with 'b0' in its name.

I have tried all combinations of using `not`, `is.not`, `!`, etc. but nothing seems to work.

E.g. `--host-filter "search=loc1 and not search=a0"` Or `--host-filter "search=loc1 and search=!a0"`

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks!